# Akka http using java - get String from RequestEntity

Tags: java, asynchronous, akka, unmarshalling, akka-http

I'm trying to get the body of an http request, but it seems like it's not as simple as it might sound, unless of course I'm missing something.

I have an instance of the `HttpRequest` (from `akka.http.javadsl.model`) and from that I can get the `RequestEntity`, but I can't figure out how to extract the string out of the entity.
I want to do that synchronously, just a simple operation of getting the string out of there.

I tried two different paths:

(1)

```
Source<ByteString, Object> source = RequestEntity.getDataBytes();
```

I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do with the `source`, it has a lot of methods, and it's unclear how to use those and if any of them can actually help me.

(2)

```
Unmarshaller<HttpEntity, String> unmarshaller = Unmarshaller.entityToString();
CompletionStage<String> result = unmarshaller.unmarshall(entity, ExecutionContext, Materializer);
```

Calling `unmarshaller.unmarshall` requires not only an instance of `RequestEntity` but also an `ExecutionContext` and a `Materializer` which I do not have at the part of the unmarshalling, also it returns a `CompletionStage<String>` which is completely redundant as I want it to be done synced.

The documentation and examples for java don't help much as they are very short and brief if they exist at all, for example in the [Marshalling & Unmarshalling section](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/java/http/routing-dsl/marshalling.html):

> Use the predefined Unmarshaller.entityToString,
>   Unmarshaller.entityToByteString, Unmarshaller.entityToByteArray,
>   Unmarshaller.entityToCharArray to convert to those basic types

As you can see, this isn't very informative.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am wondering if you had any luck with this task?

Comment: @fnt No, I decided not to use `Akka` as the documentation and support are very bad (at least for java), it was just too frustrating.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the global `ExecutionContext` and the same `Materializer` utilized for running `akka-http`. You will need to compose the `Future` that makes HTTP request with the one provided by the `Unmarshaller`:

```
    import akka.actor.ActorSystem;
    import akka.dispatch.ExecutionContexts;
    import akka.http.javadsl.Http;
    import akka.http.javadsl.model.HttpRequest;
    import akka.http.javadsl.model.HttpResponse;
    import akka.http.javadsl.model.ResponseEntity;
    import akka.http.javadsl.unmarshalling.Unmarshaller;
    import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer;
    import akka.stream.Materializer;

    ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create();
    Materializer materializer = ActorMaterializer.create(system);

    Http.get(system).
        singleRequest(HttpRequest.create("http://stackoverflow.com/"), materializer).
        thenCompose(response -> Unmarshaller.entityToString().unmarshal(response.entity(), ExecutionContexts.global(), materializer)).
        thenAccept(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Java docs are very much a work-in-progress and this is one of the areas where it lacks samples.

To answer your specific question using the `entity` directive with one of the predefined marshallers would look like this:

```
path("example", () ->
  entity(Unmarshaller.entityToString(), (string) -> {
    System.out.println("request body: " + string);
    return complete("ok");
  })
)
```

Note that it will read the entire request body into memory of the JVM which may require some thoughts. There is a default limit at 8M for request bodies which can be changed by configuration or overridden for a specific path using the `withSizeLimit` and `withoutSizeLimit` directives.

I've opened Akka ticket [21001](https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/21001) to track adding this to the docs.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I don't mind the size limit as the requests I'm planing to support don't get close to `8M`, but I just prefer to use the "low-level server api" and not the "high-level api". I'm aware of the `entity` directive, it's just that I don't want to use directives at all. So the question is how can I accomplish that from the request entity?

Comment: @johanandren do you have an example of how to create a custom unmarshaller? Looking though the javadocs, documentation and online resources doesn't amount to much.